# Check if text channel is private? JAVA JDA DV8TION

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I think this is a pretty simple question with an even more simple answer but I seriously can't manage to find out if the text channel that the event occurs in is private or not. Anyways, here's a segment of my code:

```java
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e)
    {
        if (e.isFromType(ChannelType.PRIVATE)) {
                System.out.println("locked channel");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not locked");
            }
         }
```

I want it to spit out whether the channel that I type in is private or not and that code always says its "not locked".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out a way to detect private channels now. Just gonna send this here for anyone else who encounters my issue

```java
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {

PermissionOverride po = e.getTextChannel().getPermissionOverride((IPermissionHolder) e.getGuild().getRolesByName("@everyone", true).toArray() [0]);
if (po != null && po.getDenied().contains(Permission.MESSAGE_READ)) {
                //System.out.println("locked channel");
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to know whether the message received is from a direct message. (a private channel is a direct message basically) You might want to try to override the onPrivateMessageReceived() method.

```
@Override
public void onPrivateMessageReceived(final PrivateMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    // your code here handling DM messages
}
```

When this method is triggered, it will only handle the direct messages received.